# Updating objects for static site on AWS and not seeing the results appear in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-s3, web-deployment

I am having two issues with using AWS S3 and AWS Cloud front services to deploy a static site. The first problem occurring is that I'm not seeing the changes I make to my `index.html` page when I look up http://.point.plumbing . However if I go to my bucket and access the **Object: index.html** and click on the **link** you will see the desired changes in effect https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/point.plumbing/index.html

The second issue that I am having is that I seem to be getting this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://www.point.plumbing/fontkit/avenir_55_oblique-webfont.woff2`the error is telling me that the server **cant** load some of my fonts I want on http://.point.plumbing

On the services page if you click on the icons you will see that I am not getting the font `avenirmedium, sans-serif` to load.

I've spent quite a bit of time trouble shooting these issues and the closest I have come to a solution is with this link. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ReplacingObjectsSameName.html

Is the reason why I'm getting errors and not seeing the desired changes arrive on http://.point.plumbing is because my objects cache is not refreshed for 24 hours?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I noticed you said your endpoint is `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/point.plumbing`. Check the console, your web endpoint is actually `point.plumbing.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` (I assume point.plumbing is something with a valid top level domain).

If I'm understanding correctly, you said you aren't seeing changes to the HTML when you view it via CloudFront. This is because CloudFront caches your files - [by default for 24 hours](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html). In order to see updates, you need to specify a shorter TTL via HTTP headers in the Object Metadata or issue an API command to [Invalidate the objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html). This takes 10 to 15 minutes to propagate and will start costing you money after the first 1000 objects per month.

About the fonts, I'm not sure but sounds like maybe a permissions issue. Make sure the object has permissions for `public-read` or set public `get-object` permissions on the bucket.